# File action modal in brave inconsistent placement and size (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: 22.04, brave

When I upload/download files in Brave, the modal window that interacts with the file system sometimes opens up larger than full screen, sometimes is on the other monitor, sometimes is small... it's all over the place.

Is this a Brave issue, or an Ubuntu 22.04 issue? Didn't have this problem on 20.04...